# Most efficient way to have multiple criteria in an IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I hoping to achieve 2 things here.

1. I want to know if there is a way to make this multiple criteria IF statement shorter/more efficient. ie. how would this be done if using *VBA best practices*?
2. Is there a way to name each column as a range or variable on sheet 'upload file'? This works fine, I just want to know if there is a way that is better or if there is a 'best practices' method that would work better.

Thank you

```
    If (bulksheet.range("b" & x).Value = "keyword" Or bulksheet.range("b" & x).Value = "product targeting") And bulksheet.range("d" & x).Value = campaign And bulksheet.range("p" & x).Value = "enabled" And _
bulksheet.range("r" & x).Value = "enabled" And (matchtype = "broad" Or matchtype = "phrase" Or matchtype = "exact" Or matchtype = "targeting expression" Or matchtype = "targeting expression predefined") Then
    uploadfile.range("a" & uploadrowcounter).Value = campaign
    uploadfile.range("f" & uploadrowcounter).Value = adgroup
    uploadfile.range("i" & uploadrowcounter).Value = keyword
    uploadfile.range("n" & uploadrowcounter).Value = "enabled"
    uploadfile.range("j" & uploadrowcounter).Value = targetingid
    uploadfile.range("k" & uploadrowcounter).Value = matchtype
```

Comment: It might be better to focus on one question at a time.

Comment: The most efficient approach would be to split up that long line into multiple nested `If Then` statements - no need to test C,D,E,etc if A and B already failed.   There's no "short-circuiting" in VBA so all clauses are evaluated, even f the first has failed to pass.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is hundreds of times faster...

---

```
Dim v, w

v = bulksheet.Range("a" & x & ":r" & x)

If v(1, 2) = "keyword" Or v(1, 2) = "product targeting" Then
  If v(1, 4) = campaign Then
    If v(1, 16) = "enabled" Then
      If v(1, 18) = "enabled" Then
        Select Case matchtype
          Case "broad", "phrase", "exact", "targeting expression", "targeting expression predefined"
            With uploadfile.Range("a" & uploadrowcounter & ":n" & uploadrowcounter)
              w = .Value2
              w(1, 1) = campaign
              w(1, 6) = adgroup
              w(1, 9) = keyword
              w(1, 14) = "enabled"
              w(1, 10) = targetingid
              w(1, 11) = matchtype
              .Value2 = w
            End With
        End Select
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
```

---

Research Short-circuiting Conditional Expressions in VBA.

Research Variant Arrays for Speed in VBA.

Comment: To the brave lad that just marked down this answer... explain yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about efficiency but `Select Case` is useful for multiple ORs and loops for ANDs.

```vb
    Dim b(4) As Boolean, i As Integer
    Select Case matchtype
        Case "broad", "phrase", "exact", "targeting expression", _
             "targeting expression predefined"
            b(0) = True
    End Select
    
    With bulksheet
        Select Case .Cells(x, "B")
            Case "keyword", "product targeting": b(1) = True
        End Select
        b(2) = (.Cells(x, "D").Value = campaign)
        b(3) = (.Cells(x, "P").Value = "enabled")
        b(4) = (.Cells(x, "R").Value = "enabled")
    End With

    ' AND
    For i = 1 To UBound(b)
       b(0) = b(0) And b(i)
    Next

    Dim ar
    ar = Array("A", campaign, "F", adgroup, "I", keyword, _
               "N", "enabled", "J", targetingid, "K", matchtype)

    If b(0) Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(ar) Step 2
            uploadfile.Cells(uploadrowcounter, ar(i)).Value = ar(i + 1)
            'Debug.Print ar(i), ar(i + 1)
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: This is much better organized than OP's code. But this is very slow code. My reading of the question was that OP was also looking for efficiency and bedt practuces.